# Regex to match only numbers , no apostrophes

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match only numbers in the following string

```
String : "40’000"
Match : "40000"
```

basically tring to ignore apostrophe.

I am using C#, in case it matters. 
Cant use any C# methods, need to only use Regex.

Comment: Only without apostrophes? How about like `40’-000`, it should be `40000` or `40-000`?

Comment: I just want to pick up numbers only, if that is possible, else ignoring the apostrophes would do `40000`

Comment: If your source string contains only that numbers (with or without apostropes) - probably it's better to use `Convert.ToInt32` or `Int32.TryParse` instead of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Replace like this it replace all char excpet numbers

```
string input = "40’000";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\d]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said; *I just want to pick up numbers only,* how about without regex?

```
var s = "40’000";
var result = new string(s.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(result); // 40000
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but I can only use regex

Comment: @ShankyJain Is there _any_ special reason for that?

Comment: Yup, the code handles multiple things like Names as well , we fetch the regex from the database and then apply it on the string we get.
Moreover, if I get 40'000.00 it would parse it as 4000000 and not 40000

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use regex to find the special characters not the digits, and then replace by `''`.

So a simple `(?=\S)\D` should be enough, the `(?=\S)` is to ignore the whitespace at the end of number.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tE5hS9/2)

Answer (score 0):

Replace like this it replace all char excpet numbers and points

```
string input = "40’000";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\d^.]", "");
```

Comment: I mean this answer : `string input = "40’000.00"; string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\d.]", "");` But the trouble occures when 2 or more points is appeared

Answer (score -1):

Don't complicate your life, use Regex.Replace

```
string s = "40'000";
string replaced = Regex.Replace(s, @"\D", "");
```

Comment: @SonerGönül is this better?

Comment: Since \D = [^0-9], why have you put [\D]? I mean why are you specifying it as a single character when it already is a single character?

Comment: @AnshulRai because I wand to remove any non-digit char...?

Comment: I get that, my query is that since \D is already a **single** character and `[ ]` is a character class to also match a single character. So when you put [\D] you are saying *take a single character from the single character given in the character class.* The brackets are redundant, `"\D" would be enough to match.

Comment: @AnshulRai Oh right ! I'm not (yet) a regex master, thanks !